# histogram of sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, histogram, sorting

I had to make a histogram of a given array, the frequency of the numbers in the array should be marked with *.

My program works, the problem is that the array isn't sorted correctly if there is a negative number in the array.

```
    public class Histogram {

//number in the counter is shown as *
private static String convertToStars(int num){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int j = 0; j < num; j++){
        builder.append('*');
    }
    return builder.toString();
}


public static void outputHistogram(Integer[] array) {

    //if array is empty
    if(array.length == 0){
        System.out.println("Keine Elemente vorhanden.");
        return;
    }

    //array is cloned, so it is possible to delete same numbers
    Integer[] copy = array.clone();
    Arrays.sort(copy);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copy) + "\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++){
        int counter = 1;

        for(int j = 0; j < copy.length; j++){

            if(i != j && array[i] == array[j]){
                counter++;
                copy[j] = null;
            }


        }

        if(copy[i] != null){            
            System.out.println("\t" + array[i] + "\t" + convertToStars(counter));
            }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] array = {2, 4, 23, 23, 23, 2, -8, 56, 4, 2};      
    Histogram h = new Histogram();
    System.out.println("Histogramm des Arrays: " );
    h.outputHistogram(array);
}
```

}

The negative ones should be sorted before the positive numbers. It wasn't possible to upload an image. Anyway, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have interchanged the uses of `array` and `copy` within your nested loops.

You keep the inplaced sorted `copy` for printing purpose and manipulate your original `array` and the controlling variable, else you lose the information of in placed sorted array.

```
for (int j = 0; j < copy.length; j++) {

    if (i != j && copy[i] == copy[j]) {
        counter++;
        array[j] = null;
    }

}

if (array[i] != null) {
    System.out.println("\t" + copy[i] + "\t"
            + convertToStars(counter));
}
```

Gives the correct output,

```
Histogramm des Arrays: 
[-8, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 23, 23, 23, 56]

    -8  *
    2   ***
    4   **
    23  ***
    56  *
```